# Wrong expected value of sum of Poisson process wait times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, poisson-process

Assuming a Poisson process $N_t$ and denoting wait times $S_k$ (i.e. times until the $k$-th jump), I want to find the expected value of their sum:
$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k\right]\;. $$
It is an exercise in O. Calin's *An Informal Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications* and I actually know how to do it. For instance using the integrated Poisson process
$$ U_t = \int_0^t N_s \,\mathrm{d}s $$
and the result
$$ U_t = tN_t - \sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k\;. $$
Taking the expected value of both sides and using its linearity gives
$$ \frac12 \lambda t^2 = \lambda t^2 - \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k\right], $$
so the answer is $\frac12\lambda t^2$.

The problem is that I can calculate the expected value using a different straighforward method, getting a different (apparently wrong) answer. And the question is why.

In the second method we note that $N_t=n$ for different $n$ are disjoint events. So we can calculate the conditional expectations
$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k \middle| N_t = n\right] $$
and sum over $n$ with the corresponding proabilities:
$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{Pr}(N_t=n)\times\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k \middle| N_t = n\right]\;. $$
Using
$$ S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + \dots + S_n = nT_1 + (n-1)T_2 + \dots + 2T_{n-1} + T_n $$
and independence of inter-arrival times $T_k$ we get for the conditional expectation
$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k \middle| N_t = n\right] = \frac{n(n+1)}{2\lambda}\;. $$
This is in fact the result of another exercise (3.11.4). The probability is just Poisson
$$ \mathrm{Pr}(N_t=n) = \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\;. $$
Putting it together:
$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} S_k\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} \times \frac{n(n+1)}{2\lambda} = \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t} \frac t2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} (n+2) = \frac12\lambda t^2 + t\;. $$
So there is an extra $t$.

Now I am stuck and can't find neither an error in the calculation, nor a reason why the summation over $n$ could be wrong.

Comment: Very related to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897035/expected-value-of-the-total-waiting-time-of-all-passengers-catching-a-train

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, understanding where the core problem is, I can see now it is the same. Someone doing the exercises in Calin like me may not likely spot it though as it is posed differently and the error is reinforced by another exercise – like I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not very proficient in probability so I cannot help you further than this but I think it is helpful:

I believe the incorrect step is when you take the conditional expectation following
$$S_{1}+\dots+S_{n} = nT_1+\dots+T_{n}.$$
In [these notes from MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/resources/mit6_262s11_chap02/) on page 92 we find $$E[T_{i}|N_{t}=n] = \frac{t}{n+1}$$
so that
$$E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_{t}}S_{k}\bigg| N_{t}=n\right] =\frac{nt}{2}.$$
This then yields the correct result:
$$E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\bigg|N_{t}=n\right]=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{t^{2}\lambda}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!} = \frac{t^{2}\lambda}{2}.$$

Comment: This means exercises 3.11.4 (b) and (c) in Calin are wrong (because they give the expression I did), which I am noting here for posterity.

Comment: @Yeti I don’t have the book but I want to point out that your calculations are correct if it instead was (normal) expectation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exercise indeed gives the expression for the conditional expectation with $N_t=n$, not just plain expected value.